# Direct link to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a structure of Activities like A (home Activity), which navigates to B which navigates to C.  C also has a direct link via an external launcher such as NFC or HTTP as per this pseudocode:

```
<activity "C"
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="gizmos" />
...
```

That all works fine, and I've got the "Up" and "Back" buttons navigating to B as expected even if the user started on C via an NFC scan or HTTP link.  The issue is that if the user starts on C, and then hits the home button to get to the launcher, and then launches the app via the Launcher, they end up on A, the home screen.

I'd like the user to resume their work at C.  How do I do this?

I've read through [this document](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) but it doesn't seem to address this particular case, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app always starts with the Main Activity unless it is called with an Intent. If you want to change this behaviour you can store a key (like A, B or C) in the settings that is read in Activity A onCreate to call another Activity from there.

Comment: I would even go so far as saying you should have another Activity like LaunchDispatcher that decides whether to go to A, B or C and make sure you set its flags appropriately so it isn't placed in the back stack